# nslookup output

Tags: bash, dns, ip-address, nslookup

Here's some simple output from nslookup:
    nslookup www.go2linux.org
    Server:         4.2.2.2
    Address:        4.2.2.2#53

What does `#53` mean over there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

53 is a DNS server port number.

Comment: Answers "Port number" and "DNS server port numbers" were rejected because they were under 30 characters.

Comment: Oh ok, that is what I thought also. The sharp character confused me a bit, I thought you had to specify a port by putting `:` in front, not `#`. Thanks.